# Flash Builder AIR Project Background Image

Tags: apache-flex, air, background-image, flash-builder

I'm very new to Flash Builder and am trying to create an AIR app with a custom background. How can I put a background image in my project? I've tried just placing the image in the design view but it never shows up when I run the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it myself, by adding

`@Embed(source='/path/to/file.jpg')`

instead of what the browse function put:

`/path/to/file.jpg`

I got the idea from seeing how the icon on a button (which showed up) was written.

Edit: After some more tinkering, it seems that /path/to/file works just as well, as long as the file is under the src directory, and that "Copy non-embedded files to output folder" is checked in the Project properties under Flex Compiler.

Comment: it would be great if you could a bit more detail about *where* this embed code is occuring and what other functions are necessary

Answer (score 0):

In the Design view of your mxml file, 
if you have the standard properties view like this (figure 1),
 change it to the A-Z (figure 2) and scroll down to background image

[image: Standard Properties view]

[image]